# Convert characters to html equivalent using .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascii

I have a text document that is a roster of licensees. I am looping through this document to create a html table of this data. I've come across names with non standard characters.

This is one of them

> Aimeé

I tried running all the inputs through the following function, but when it comes across the above character it doesn't replace it.

```
Function ReplaceBadCharacters(ByVal input As String) As String
  Return input.Replace(Chr(233), "&#233;")
End Function
```

How can I replace each character with the html equivalent?

**EDIT**

When I debug the above function it shows the input as Aime[] and not Aimeé.

In Chrome it looks like this Aime�

Comment: When I open the document in notepad++ it shows the encoding as ANSI. When I change it to UTF-8 in notepad++, it shows that character as `xE9`

Comment: that sounds like é might be a different glyph.  What type of text documents are your rosters in?  .docx, .doc, .pdf, etc might insert non-standard glyphs for the non-standard chars.  If it's a .txt or any ASCII based document, check the encoding.  You might be reading the file as UTF8 and the document is UTF## or vice-versa.  Also make sure you specify the encoding type when you read the file.

Comment: It's just a csv file. When I read the file, can I specifiy ANSI? I don't see it listed in the Encoding types.

Comment: Hmmm... 0x0E9 is the hex form of the number 233. Try encoding the string with the ANSI encoding in your code and see if that fixes it.  EDIT:  Try `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`

Comment: The input file was not in the correct format.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the solution.  Did you try the `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`?  That could be the encoder you need to do it all in code.

Comment: Even better! That works perfectly. With this, I won't have to care what format the file is in, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that.
As long as your page is encoded as UTF8, the characters will work fine.

However, you do need to call `Server.HtmlEncode` to escape HTML special characters.
(Unless you're printing the strings in a `<%: %>` block or a Razor `@` block, which escapes them for you)

Comment: I added a meta tag with charset=UTF-8 to the head and it still doesn't show up. I also tried server.htmlencode and no luck. Is it possible that the input file is not in the right format?

Comment: Try the `Encoding` property in the `Page` declaration.

Comment: Does the `Encoding` need to be on the vb or the aspx?

Comment: I opened the file in notepad, saved it as UTF-8, read the file as `Encoding.UTF8` and it worked like you said! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

é is in the current ASCII char set.  If you put that into the HTML, it will render correctly (just like how it shows up correctly in the browser when you look at this page)

but if you want to replace all instances of it, use this instead `&eacute;`

```
input.Replace("é", "&eacute;")
```

Comment: I added an edit to the original post. It never sees the actual character é.